# why no tailOption in Scala?

Tags: scala

Why is no `tailOption` in Scala, if there is `headOption` ?

This is an [old](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/3137.html) question, found no answer on google.

Comment: What would the tail of an option be?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no need for `tailOption`. If you want a function behaving like `tail`. but returning empty collection when used on empty collection, you can use `drop(1)`. I often use this when I want to handle empty collection gracefully when creating a list of pairs:

```
s zip s.drop(1)
```

If you want `None` on empty collection and `Some(tail)` on non-empty one, you can use:

```
s.headOption.map(_ => s.tail)
```

or (if you do not mind exception to be thrown and captured, which may be a bit slower):

```
Try {s.tail}.toOption
```

I can hardly imagine a reasonable use case for the other options, though.

Comment: so `def tailOption = drop(1) andThen headOption` or stg like that

Comment: @jhegedus no, `drop(1) andThen headOption` is incorrect

Answer (score 2):

I never though of this before, it's kind of intriguing why tailOption in not part of the standard library. I don't know about why it is not there, but we can definitely extend the functionality by catching the error thrown by tail of empty list.

```
def getOption[A](a: => A) = {
   try{ Some(a) }
   catch { case e: Exception => None }
}

getOption(List(1,2,3).tail) // Some(3)
getOption(Nil.tail)  // None
```

Comment: There should be runtime overhead for throwing/catching exceptions.

Comment: `def getOption[A](a: => A) = scala.util.Try(a).toOption`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code.

```
s match {
          case head :: tail => Option(tail)
          case _ => None
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Actually, there is `lastOption` which does exactly what you want

Comment: Not so. `last` returns `A` and `lastOption` returns `Option[A]` while `tail` (on a `List`, for example) returns a `List[A]` and `tailOption`, if it existed, would return an `Option[List[A]]`. Not the same thing at all.